# How to check if one file is inside another?

Tags: java, file

Im having a (quite stupid) problem I guess.

I have two File classes, and I want to return `true` if one is inside the other. False if not. I cant just compare the parent files because `/a/b/c/d` is also a subfolder of `/a/b`.

My first approach was something like this:

```
boolean areSubsets(File f1, File f2) {
    if (f1.getAbsolutePath().contains(f2.getAbsolutePath()) ||
            f2.getAbsolutePath().contains(f1.getAbsolutePath()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that there are false positives this way.

I.e if we have `f1` with path=`/storage/abc` and `f2` with `/storage/abcabc`

that would return `true` which is wrong.

Comment: If you use Java 7+ you should use `Path`; it does have the tools for that

Comment: I concur use `Path` instead and if you need to then use #getCanonicalPath

Comment: @King that would be `.toRealPath()`

Comment: @fge oh yes.. IOexception.

Comment: Well, it is much better to handle an `IOException`, then using the wrong `File#getAbsolutePath` or `Path#toAbsolutePath` method (in my  opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on `/`:

```
boolean areSubsets(File f1, File f2) throws IOException {
    String[] p = f1.getCanonicalPath().split("/");
    String[] q = f2.getCanonicalPath().split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length && i < q.length; i++)
        if (!p[i].equals(q[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Based on fge's comment, in Java 7 you can do the following:

```
boolean areSubsets(File f1, File f2) {
    Path path1 = f1.toPath();
    Path path2 = f2.toPath();
    return path1.startsWith(path2) || path2.startsWith(path1);
}
```

Comment: `#getAbsolutePath` is error-prone for that task. Use `#getCanonicalPath` instead. For example I could create `f1` as `new File("../blub/../blub/../blub/abc/sub");` and `f2` as `new File("abc");` and `#getAbsolutePath` would "fail" here.

Comment: Btw mind that `#getCanonicalPath` can throw an `IOException`.

Comment: @Tom there is no need to overengineer it.

Comment: @Tom ok, convinced.... but it's an overkill if the user provides paths without `.`, `..`. `getCanonicalPath` will also resolve symbolic links, meaning access to the fs, when we only want string manipulation.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but since "we" can't trust a user, we have keep bad file paths in mind :).

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to use `startsWith()` on the paths, but add a slash to the "container":

```
File f1, f2;

boolean contains = f2.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(
    f1.getCanonicalPath() + "/");
```

Comment: `#getAbsolutePath` is error-prone for that task. Use `#getCanonicalPath` instead. For example I could create `f1` as `new File("../blub/../blub/../blub/abc/sub");` and `f2` as `new File("abc");` and `#getAbsolutePath` would "fail" here.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if you use Java 7+:

```
final Path testedPath = Paths.get(...).toAbsolutePath();
final Path candidateParent = Paths.get(...).toAbsolutePath();

return testedPath.startsWith(candidateParent)
    && !testedPath.equals(candidateParent);
```

Note that there is .toRealPath(), however it can throw an IOException.